# Select all from table Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g

I wrote a stored procedure to select all records from a table. Since I'm new to Oracle I have few questions.

1. Is this Correct?
2. Is this the best way to select all records from a table?
3. How can I view result in SP in DB level?

```
alter PROCEDURE employee_getall
(

 cv_results in out sys_refcursor
)
IS
BEGIN
open cv_results for
   select *
    from employee_master
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL ;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you want to select everything from a stored procedure? How do you plan to call/use this, and the result set it gets? Why are you trapping and squashing all exceptions?

Comment: I dont know the proper way to do this. But I want select all from the table. I'm calling this through C# program and returning a data set.

Comment: In Employee Master screen I want to show the all employee records. For that I need to do this.

Comment: If you're new to Oracle can I just suggest you never use WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL

Comment: It's `create procedure` not `alter procedure`. Assuming you don't have an ORM and you don't want people writing SQL directly against your DB (i.e. you're deliberately using stored procedures as an API and removing direct access) then this is probably the simplest way. In addition to previous comments `cv_results` doesn't need to be an `in` parameter.

Comment: If the only thing your stored procedure does is open a cursor and return it I think you'd be better off just executing this particular SQL statement through whatever API you're using and getting the cursor back that way. IMO writing a stored procedure which performs no logic is pointless.

Comment: When I run across this in a production environment, I am going to be rather uncharitable. My initial thoughts are going to be "*What the plastic?*" and "*What syphilitic idiot created this abortion?*" (I wouldn't verbalize those thoughts, not be before a pause at least.) Correct? maybe syntactically correct. The best way to retrieve all rows from a table? It's a good way to increase complexity and obfuscation.

Comment: It's not completely pointless @Bob - it's a pattern commonly used in high-security environments such as banking (though it's highly unusual to return an unfiltered table in that context). The idea is that you never grant direct access to the DB to your API you have some procedures in `schemaA`, which you access through `schemaB` and then only let your API see `schemaB`. This enables you to use the DBs security measures to stop people accidentally giving access to more data than they're allowed. (I'm unsure how effective this is)

Comment: using `select *` isn't good practice either, perhaps you have used it here as a shortcut, but it should not be used in production code.